# Unable to access protocol function in TableViewcell class in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview

I want to access a function present in the protocol in tableviewcell class.But unable to do it. can anyone help me to fix this problem?

```
protocol updateLcodeCell: class {
    func updateAfterSearchApiCall(searchTextArray: [String]?)
}


class PatientFormTableViewController: UIViewController{

var lcodeDelegate: updateLcodeCell?

func callApi(arr: [String]){
 lcodeDelegate?.updateAfterSearchApiCall(searchTextArray: arr)}
}
```

**In my cell class**

```
class LcodeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

 weak var lcodeDelegate: updateLcodeCell?


 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.lcodeDelegate = self
    }

}
extension LcodeTableViewCell: updateLcodeCell{
    func updateAfterSearchApiCall(searchTextArray: [String]?) {
        searcApiResponseDataArray = searchTextArray
    }
  
}
```

Comment: @Tapan....hey the answer is helpful or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your tableView `indexPath.row` method call your delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourCellId, for: indexPath) as! YourCustomTableCell
 cell.lcodeDelegate = self // here call your delegate

 return cell
}
```